# Nancy self host returns 404

Tags: c#, nancy, self-hosting

I have a console app which i want to use Nancy to host a web service.
here is my **Program.cs**

```
namespace NancyConsole
{
    using Nancy.Hosting.Self;
    using System;
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:1234";
            var host = new NancyHost(new Uri(url));
            host.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started, now listening on " + url);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            host.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my **MainModule.cs** file

```
namespace NancyConsole
{
    using Nancy;
    internal class MainModule : NancyModule
    {
        public MainModule()
        {
            Get["/"] = x => View["Views/index.html"];
        }
    }
}
```

This is my project structure
[image: The project structure]

When i run the project this is the error i get on the browser 
[image: Error Message]

I dont know where i am going wrong? Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try run as admin. Maybe Vs did not reserve port. Did you reserve port:  netsh http add urlacl url = http://*:1234/ user=[USER]

Comment: I did not run on VS, i compiled the solution then i went to the Debug folder and run the exe as Administrator

Comment: @MRsa It is also possible to pass the HostConfiguration with the option RewriteLocalhost = false to the NancyHost constructor so that you do not need to setup url acls. Of course then this only binds localhost and will not be accessible from other nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the module public. The default loading strategy uses reflection to find public module classes.

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Introduction):

> It is important that you declare your module public, otherwise NancyFx is not able to discover your module.